# Dropal 8 : RouteSubscriber class does not exist in RegisterEventSubscribersPass

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

got a serious issue with Drupal 8.2.3 site, it was fine until my hosting company notified me of "repeated attacks" and have temporarily taken the site down by editing the .htaccess.

I have tried to bring the site back up and update it but all I get is the following

> This website is temporarily down for maintenance, it will be back
>   online again soon. Please accept our apologies for any inconvenience.

I have made a local copy and tried to update the core but with no luck, I even created a new site with a new database but as soon as I try to import the database the error comes back.

After checking the php error logs I found this but unfortunately I'm new to Drupal and have no idea how to fix it.

```
[22-May-2018 17:35:48 UTC] ReflectionException: Class Drupal\token\Routing\RouteSubscriber does not exist in f:\example\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterEventSubscribersPass.php on line 30 #0 f:\example\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterEventSubscribersPass.php(30): ReflectionClass->__construct('Drupal\\token\\Ro...')
#1 f:\example\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\Compiler\Compiler.php(107): Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterEventSubscribersPass->process(Object(Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#2 f:\example\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\ContainerBuilder.php(593): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile(Object(Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder))
#3 f:\example\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(1254): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile()
#4 f:\example\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(866): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer()
#5 f:\example\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(461): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer()
#6 f:\example\core\lib\Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel.php(651): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot()
#7 f:\example\index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#8 {main}
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are running a version of Drupal core that is not secure. You should operate under the assumption that your site has been comprised, please reference [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/security/your-drupal-site-got-hacked-now-what) from the Drupal Security Team.

Your number one priority should be getting core to at least version 8.4.8 on your site. There have been multiple highly critical security updates to core since 8.2.3. Most importantly: [SA-CORE-2018-002](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2018-002) and [SA-CORE-2018-004](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2018-004). Information and patches (if need be) can be found at those links.

The maintenance message may be something configured by your cloud host. Reach out to them and ask what steps you need to take to get your .htaccess rules updated etc. If it is the Drupal core maintenance message please reference [this documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/extend-maintenance.html#_enabling_or_disabling_maintenance_mode_using_drush) from the user guide.

Hopefully the error message is related to your site being out of date. If it persists after your core updates, check your [PHP version compatibility](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/system-requirements/php-requirements).

Comment: hey, thanks for your advice, I have reached out to my hosting and they changed the .htaccess which I changed back and have updated the core to 8.4.8 and my PHP version to 7.1.16 but the PHP error remains.

Comment: Is your token module installed and enabled and on version 8.x-1.1?

Comment: yes, I'm not sure why but I manually updated that plugin and it fixed the error.